# net c# ftp request is caching result

Tags: c#, caching, ftpwebrequest

I'm using FtpWebRequest class in Net 4.5 to execute some commands against an FTP server

Goggling I find that the recommendation for detecting if a file/directory exists is sending a Ftp.GetDateTimestamp command, so that's what I'm doing. The steps I'm doing are as follow:

1. Try to add a package 1 (files and folders) to a directory. Since the package doesn't know if the directory already exists, it has to check it first
2. Execute "GetDateTimestamp", which throws if the directory does not exist. So, in this step it throws, cause it doesn't exist
3. Execute "MakeDirectory", to create the directory
4. Try to add a package 2 to the directory. Since the package doesn't know that a previous package was already added, it has to first check if the directory exists
5. Execute "GetDateTimestamp". It still throws. Why???
6. Since previous step said the directory doesn't exist, code tries to create it, but given it in fact exists, it throws

I tried setting the CachePolicy property of each request to some RequestCachePolicy/RequestCacheLevel values, but it didn't work

I'm about to change the implementation of the DirectoryExists method to list parent directory items, but I would like if it's possible to make it work with the actual definition

****Note: I won't be using any 3rd party libraries****

Thanks in advance